# Keep Background Image Consistent Throughout Site HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, background, tabs

I have a home page and then 4 tabs which switch to different html files. You click "About" tab and it switches to about.html file. All 4 tabs / files use the same CSS file (main.css). This being said, they all use the same background image. The problem I am having is that when I click on one of the tabs, the background image disappears for a split second and then reappears as if it has to load up again for every tab. What do I do to fix it so the image doesn't disappear every time I click on a tab so it stays consistent throughout the site?

Here is the CSS code for adding the background image

`body {
    background: url("IMG_0462.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Here is the HTML code that I am using for the tabs

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo">
            <h1>Adam Birdsall</h1>
            <h2>Software Engineer</h2>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <section>


                </section>

            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add some code or a live URL

Comment: Sorry about that.. I added the code that is used. The HTML code is the same for all my .html files. (index.html, contact.html, etc.)

Comment: I would send a URL but its not live yet. Only running locally right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added each link as a separate page and these pages need to load for you to see them, even though the browser will most likely cache your image, there is a "reload" happening.

If you aiming to have a smooth transition without a page load you have to use an Ajax call (or some other javascript/CSS i.e. client based technique).

You could look at examples of such sites all over the web, one such example that I found that could be useful to you is [here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html#page1)

Unfortunately its not an easy hack or fix, however you will certainly enjoy doing this and there will certainly be no image disappearance.